# Way to encrypt files on hard disk so that no one could use them?

Tags: windows, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt files on hard disk under windows with strong encryption so that no one could use them?

Say, before I leave my pc, I run this procedure and all *needed* files get encrypted. Then I get back and decrypt those files.

Comment: Just remember the larger the encryption the more time it will take to encrypt and/or decrypt.

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at [TrueCrypt - Free Open-Source On-The-Fly Disk Encryption Software ...](http://www.truecrypt.org/) Also, some editions of Windows 7 have Bitlocker  but I think thats just Ultimate and Enterprise, I'm not sure about Professional.

Comment: Correct.  It's not available on Win7 Pro.

Comment: however Win7-Pro does support Encrypting File System.  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System

Answer (score 1):

PGP is the only way I know that is to this day "full proof" (I say that reluctantly since nothing is "full proof", but PGP has not been cracked as of yet, unlike True Crypt).  There are many other strong encryption, but PGP is the strongest (so strong the government tried to shut them down because it was too good).  Comes with a good UI too.